# WHMCS: How to get the current client in addon module clientarea page?

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

Given that I have a WHMCS addon that I call 'my_addon'. I created the main addon file `'my_addon.php'` which does contain nothing than:

```
<?php

function my_addon_clientarea($vars) {
    $client = null;
    return array(
        'pagetitle' => 'My Addon',
        'breadcrumb' => array('index.php?m=my_addon'=>'My Addon'),
        'templatefile' => 'views/myaddon_view',
        'vars' => array(
            'client' => $client
        )
    );
}
```

This does basically work. It does give me my template file, everything is passed through. My question is: How do I get the currently logged in client from within that function?

I didn't find any API method and I can't see any constant which does hold this information.

There must be a way to get the current client within the clientarea? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who do come after me and have the same problem: it's easy to solve. Turned out, that I just had to think it through... I found the client id to be available in the `$_SESSION`-variable.

So, if you are looking for the client's id:

```
<?php

function my_addon_clientarea($vars) {
    $clientid = $_SESSION['uid'];

    // And so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The official way to get current user information is:

```
$currentUser = new \WHMCS\Authentication\CurrentUser;
$user = $currentUser->user();
```

You can find more information [here](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/authentication/)